# remove unnecessary comma from python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

My dict is,

```
d= {'add1':'','add2':'address2','add3':'' }
```

I want to join all the values as a list of comma separated words.

if d is `d= {'add1':'','add2':'address2','add3':'' }`

then output would be `address2`

if d is `d= {'add1':'address1','add2':'address2','add3':'' }`

then output would be `address1,address2`

if d is `d= {'add1':'address1','add2':'address2','add3':'address3' }`

then output would be `address1,address2,address3`

if d is `d= {'add1':'','add2':'','add3':'' }`

then output would be `''` (simply blank string)

What I have tried ?

```
",".join([d.get('add1',''), d.get('add2',''), d.get('add3','')])
```

but I am not getting output as I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to worry about order

```
','.join(value for value in d.itervalues() if value)
```

If your keys are always add1 etc, they will be easily sortable to ensure order

```
','.join(d[key] for key in sorted(d.keys()) if d[key])
```

Comment: Your first example is not working (invalid syntax). You need `value for value in...`.

Comment: Thanks @luator, I missed that. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may simply join non-empty values:

```
','.join(v for v in d.itervalues() if v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter out the empty stings first:

```
",".join([x for x in d.values() if x])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension after getting `d.values()` and then `str.join()` -

```
','.join([v for v in d.values() if v])
```

Demo -

```
>>> d= {'add1':'','add2':'address2','add3':'' }
>>> ','.join([v for v in d.values() if v])
'address2'
>>> d= {'add1':'address1','add2':'address2','add3':'' }
>>> ','.join([v for v in d.values() if v])
'address1,address2'
>>> d= {'add1':'','add2':'','add3':'' }
>>> ','.join([v for v in d.values() if v])
''
>>> d= {'add1':'address1','add2':'address2','add3':'address2' }
>>> ','.join([v for v in d.values() if v])
'address1,address2,address2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict.values()` method and `filter` function:

`','.join(filter(None, d.values()))`